# Count, index out of range

Tags: python

I have this code to return a number but I get the error: IndexError: index out of range: 0 
with the return.

```
nbus=1

users = []

for i in range(nb):

    ind = (int(nbus)-1)

ind= ind +1 

return users[ind]
```

Do you know why?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You never append to `users`, therefore it contains no elements and has no valid indexes.

Comment: when I do the append, I get an other error: iteration over non-sequence